# clicking on select box that goes outside popup closes the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a popup, and inside I have a select box which options goes outside the popup. So, to close my popup I need to click outside, the problem is when I select an option from the select box that is outside, its closing also the popup :/

this is my popup:

```
    <div id="form-modal" style="display:none" >

    <div id="form-modal-meeting" class="actions_" >
      <div class="action_popup">
          <div class="date-label" ><%= l(:priority) %></div>
            <select class="list_cf" id="issue_custom_field_values_27" name="issue[custom_field_values][27]"><option value="">&nbsp;</option><option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
</select>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my closing jquery function:

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.action_popup').hover(function(){
      mouse_is_inside=true;
//          introJs().exit();
    }, function(){
      mouse_is_inside=false;
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){
      if(! mouse_is_inside) {
        if ($('#form-modal-watcher').css('display') == 'block') {
          mouse_is_inside=true;
        }
        else {
          $('#form-modal').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });

      $('#ui-datepicker-div').hover(function(){
        mouse_is_inside=true;
      }, function(){
        mouse_is_inside=false;
    });


    $( ".add_watcher_btn" ).click(function() {
      mouse_is_inside=true;
    });


  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better check the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) element, if this is a descendant of your modal element, with [`jQuery::closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
$("body").mouseup(function(event){
  if(isInside(event) === false) {
    $('#form-modal').fadeOut();
  }
});

function isInside (event) {
  return $(event.target).closest('#form-modal').length !== 0;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4mjg2uwb/

Comment: this is for adding to my previous "click outside and close" function or to substitute? either way its not working :/

Comment: The answer is how you can replace your `hover` methods. You don't have to track the mouse, if it is inside or not. Just check if the element inside your container was tapped (mouseup-ed) or not. And you can do this with event.target and closest method. See my demo.

Comment: how can I make an exception with this? I have this class that If I click it closes anyway `$('#ui-datepicker-div')` (this is an outside popup plugin)

Comment: Modify `isInside` to check if target is inside ui-datepicker-div. `|| $(event.target).closest('#ui-datepicker-div').length !== 0;`